# AngularJS ng-repeat an unknown deep array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I need to have the possibility to print out a possible infinite deep array-structure into a list. Here's the code from a modified AngularJS-example where I have added some more deep children in the array. How can I print `child of child` and even its children as well? Is there a way I can get it to repeat forever as long as there is more children?

HTML

```
<div ng-app>
  <div ng-controller="TodoCtrl">
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="todo in todos">
        <span>{{todo.text}}</span>
        <ul>
          <li ng-repeat="child in todo.children">
            <span>{{child.text}}</span>
            <!-- What about the next one -->
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
function TodoCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.todos = [{
    text: 'root 1',
    children: [{
      text: 'child of root 1',
      children: [{
        text: 'child of child',
        children: []
      }]
    }]
  }, {
    text: 'root 2',
    children: []
  }];
}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/25866/

Comment: Hi, use [treeview](http://ngmodules.org/modules/angular.treeview)

Comment: there is example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eu81273/8LWUc/18/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the view recursively this way:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="todo.html">
    <div>
        <div>{{ todo.text }}</div>
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="todo in todo.children" ng-include="'todo.html'"></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</script>

<div ng-controller="MyController">
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="todo in todos" ng-include="'todo.html'"></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Here the [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/o9b431dh/) based on your sample data.